# Can king's court be "stationed" in a city?

Tags: word-choice

I want to say that when the Frederick II with his court, was in the city of Pisa, some person got a chance to see him.

Can I say "stationed with his court in", like so?

> Approximately in 1225 when Frederick II was stationed with his court in Pisa, Milo was granted an audience.

Or does **stationed** only apply to military units?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about "held his court at" or "held his court in":

> Approximately in 1225 when Frederick
>   II held his court at
>   Pisa, Milo was granted an audience.

(not sure if it's at or in)

Comment: +1 This sounds most idiomatic. I think *in* and *at* are both possible. Note that it does sound more permanent then a mere audience with a travelling Emperor: if there was some permanence in his stay in Pisa, use "held court"; otherwise, simply say "when Fredrick II was in Pisa". I am too lazy to look up whether he was actually holding his court there at the time or was just travelling. It is probably also a legal/judicial definition, as holding court implies hearing supplicants/cases.

Comment: I agree, this is the way to say it. +1 And the OP should remember that a *king* or, in this case, an emperor, especially one so brilliant he was called *stupor mundi* (wonder of the world), is never "stationed" like a common trooper.

Answer (score 3):

The term you want is *[seat](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/seat)*,

> a place in which administrative power or the like is centered: the seat of the government.

Here is an example of the use of *seat* from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avignon),

> In 1309 the city, still part of the Kingdom of Arles, was chosen by Pope Clement V as his residence, and from 9 March 1309 until 13 January 1377 was the seat of the Papacy instead of Rome.

I would suggest modifying the sentence to something like,

> Around 1225, Milo was granted an audience with Fredrick II. At the time, the seat of Fredrick's court was in Pisa.

Answer (score 0):

A court "sits" or "is seated", but that term may apply best to a more permanent location. You could always fall back on "his court, located in Pisa".

Comment: So... "... Approximately in 1225 Frederick II with his court, located in Pisa, granted Milo an audience"? Sounds wierd to me... Or "court which sat in Pisa"?

Comment: The problem may be that, because medieval courts traveled constantly, saying a court was "located" somewhere gives an incorrect impression of permanence. Even "which sat" sounds a bit permanent. "Was sitting" somehow sounds better to me, since it speaks only of a specific moment in time rather than generally.

Comment: It may be that your sentence makes it a bit awkward since it implies that the court somehow participated in granting the audience, while I think you meant to say that Frederick granted the audience, which was with him and the court: "...in 1225 Frederick II granted Milo an audience with his court, seated in Pisa." 

Or, simpler still, "...with his court in Pisa", though that could imply that he had a separate court in Pisa.

Answer (score 0):

How about *lodged* or *quartered*? The latter may sound a bit too military, though....

ALSO: *While the court was resident at ....*

Comment: Yep, it does. I think there must be something simpler - that I am missing. This can't be so "rare" of an expression, after all!

Comment: @drozzy: I added another suggestion. Or you could just rephrase to avoid the need to describe the situation of the court. Just say: "In approximately 1225, Milo obtained an audience with the court of Frederick II at Pisa."